# Ruby private class method

Tags: ruby

I tried to implement a singleton pattern in ruby, just want to know why I can not access private class method in ruby

```
class Test

    private_class_method :new
    @@instance = nil
    def self.getInstance
            if(!@@instance)
                    @@instance = Test.new
            end

            return @@instance
    end
end
```

I declare "new" as a private class method, and try to call the "new" in my singleton method "getInstance"

test output

```
>> require "./test.rb"
=> true
>> Test.getInstance
NoMethodError: private method `new' called for Test:Class
from ./test.rb:7:in `getInstance'
from (irb):2
>>
```

Comment: You cannot access `new` with a receiver because it is now private. And it is you who made it private. Not clear why you are doing such contradictory thing and wondering over it.

Comment: not sure why this is down voted. @sawa, someone with java background can make this mistake easily and I think this question can be helpful to them. In JAVA, we can access any private stuff inside a class declaration,

Comment: Ruby is not Java. Don't use a method without even knowing what it does. Not reading the document is just laziness.

Comment: I know ruby is not java. I think the forum have tolerance for newbie questions, and most people is willing to help others pass their learning curves. Save your arrogance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `::new` is a private method, you can't access it by sending a message to the class constant. It'll work to just send it to implicit `self` by omitting the receiver, though.

Additionally, since this is a class method, its instance variable scope is already class-level, so you don't need to use `@@` class variables. An instance variable will work just fine here.

```
class Test
  private_class_method :new

  def self.instance
    @instance ||= new
  end
end


puts Test.instance.object_id
puts Test.instance.object_id
# => 33554280
# => 33554280
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private_class_method :new

NoMethodError: private method `new' called for Test:Class
```

That's why. Private methods cannot be invoked with explicit receiver. Try using `send`.

```
@@instance = Test.send(:new)
```

or with implicit receiver (because `self` is `Test`)

```
@@instance = new
```